# Convert int value in txt file to float

Tags: python, python-3.x, txt

I have txt file like this f1= `255,216,255,224,0,16,74,70,73,70,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,255,219,0` I need to  convert these numbers to float and save in f2( f2 contain the converted  float values)  how can do that?

Comment: You'd start by breaking there problem into smaller bits, then with some basic research

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] after reading [ask]. If you want text output, the file already contains valid floats as far as python is concerned. Otherwise you need to be much more specific

Comment: So, just to be clear, do you expect the output in f2 to be `255.0,216.0,...`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming input is correct, using list comprehension:

```
with open(file_path, "r") as f_r:
    num_strs = f_r.read().split(",")
    num_floats = [float(x) for x in num_strs]
```

And if you want to write the output in a file:

```
separator = ","
with open(file_path, "w") as f_w:
    f_w.write(separator.join([str(x) for x in num_floats]))
```

This will write the default string representation of floats to file
If you want also to format the floats (set precision for example):

```
separator = ","
with open(file_path, "w") as f_w:
    f_w.write(separator.join([f"{x:.2f}" for x in num_floats]))
```

Comment: thanks a lot, how can write the output in file?

Comment: Added to answer

Comment: I have one value in each raw, how can update on this code please?

Comment: @oleva just change the separator to a new line in both split and join

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np
numbers = np.loadtxt("file.txt",  delimiter=",")
#It should parse it as float64 already, but just in case:
numbers=np.float64(numbers)
with open("file2.txt", "w") as txt_file:
    for number in numbers:
        txt_file.write("".join(str(number)) + ",")
```

Comment: Why bother with numpy if you aren't going to use it's features?

Comment: He said he needed it in a "float array" for the intermediate part, which I assumed by "array" he meant "np.array". He edited the question just now. Look at the question history.

Comment: How can make float number like .00000 instead of .0 ?

Answer (score -1):

I wrote a one-liner :D

```
import pathlib

# Read the text file, split it by commas, then convert all items to floats
output = list(map(float, pathlib.Path("file.txt").read_text().split(",")))
```

Comment: You also appear to have missed a major part of the question. Please add prose in addition to a code dump if you believe this answers the question.

Comment: @MadPhysicist The OP seems to have modified his original question and changed his output requirements.